# Hide the header and the tabs at the bottom on Scroll - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I hide the header and the footer (tabs at the bottom) when user starts **scrolling vertically down**

and show the tabs and header once again **on Scroll up.**

Any tutorial or documentation guide is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a tutorial for hiding the header on scroll: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abDaZnx6tkU

Comment: I will try to apply it to the footer tabs too.